# Differences in LSMEANS in R vs SPSS

Tags: r, repeated-measures, spss, ancova, lsmeans

I am trying to replicate results from SPSS in R. The model is a repeated measure ANCOVA. Funny enough: all the estimated parameter are the same (beta-coefficients, mean differences for contrasts) but for both, the standard error is different, hence *t*- and *p*-values.

In SPSS I entered the columns with the measured outcome and 3 covariates.

In R i did the following:

```
model <- nlme::lme(Y ~ (cov1 + cov2 + cov3) * time,
           random = ~ 1 | subject,
           weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | time),
           data = df,
           method = "REML")

lsmeans(model , pairwise ~ time | (cov1 + cov2 + cov3),
        adjustSigma = TRUE,
        adjust = "none")
```

Unfortunately I cant provide you with a working example. 
The results concerning the *t*-values are varying drastically. Why should that be?

Comment: What covariance matrix and what denominator degrees of freedom are you using in either program? E.g. is one using Kenward-Roger and the other Satterthwaite (or some something else)? Those would be some of my suspicions (but could be wrong).

Comment: was also thinking about it. R is definitely using Satterthwaite. SPSS i dunno. But how would DF influence SE?

Comment: True, the SE should not be affected by that (but t-value etc.). Could of course be the method for getting SEs and or optimization (REML vs. ML vs...).

Comment: Tried REML as well as ME, didn't change the results.